# Is there a way to use 64 bit user/item ids in Pyspark ALS?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml, collaborative-filtering

I am using the ALS implementation of [pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS). My user ids are 64-bit ints but the implementation forces me to use 32-bit integers (or `Int` in Scala - [see](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1296bbb8ac7f582f8689f3e2f36614cf541b80d4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L93)). Is there a solution other than mapping my ids to `Int`s? If mapping is the way to go, is there a conventional way of doing so?

Comment: can you try ```.cast("long")```. It is 64bit , if I remember right

Comment: My user ids are already in 64-bit, and from what I can tell looking at the implementation (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1296bbb8ac7f582f8689f3e2f36614cf541b80d4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L93), they require them to be `Int`s.